# Web scraping with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I have this code that fetches rates from a website called X-Rates, and outputs to excel the monthly averages of a chosen country.

The code runs quite fast, but I still think there's improvements to be done!

Apologies for long code, but if you help me I would be really grateful!

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub fetchCurrencyPast()

Dim RowNum As Long
Dim ColNum As Long
Dim RowNumB As Long
Dim ColNumB As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Period As String
Dim SCrcy As String
Dim MsgErr As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Call FormatResultSheet
Call AddHeader

Period = Application.InputBox("What's the year you want to collect back data?", "Period", , , , , 2)

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

If Len(Period) <> 4 Then
    GoTo ErrHandler
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To 9

    RowNum = 2
    RowNumB = 2
    ColNum = 4
    ColNumB = 3

    If i = 1 Then
        'ARS
        Cells(RowNum, 2).Value = "ARS"
        Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = Period

        For Each SCrcy In Array("EUR", "USD", "GBP")
            Call GetRateYear("ARS", SCrcy, Period, RowNum, ColNum)
            RowNum = 2
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
            RowNumB = RowNum
            Call GetSingleMonth("ARS", SCrcy, Period, RowNumB, ColNumB)
        Next

    End If

    If i = 2 Then
        RowNum = 14
        ColNum = 4
        'AUD
        Cells(RowNum, 2).Value = "AUD"
        Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = Period

        For Each SCrcy In Array("EUR", "USD", "GBP")
            Call GetRateYear("AUD", SCrcy, Period, RowNum, ColNum)
            RowNum = 14
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
            RowNumB = RowNum
            Call GetSingleMonth("AUD", SCrcy, Period, RowNumB, ColNumB)
        Next
    End If
```

Error Handler:

```
ErrHandler:

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    MsgErr = "Error #" & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & Err.Source & "." & Chr(10) & "Error description: " & Err.Description
    MsgBox MsgErr, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

GetRatesYear Function:

```
 Private Function GetRateYear(ByVal sFromCrcy As String, ByVal sToCrcy As String, ByVal sYear As String, ByVal RowNum As Long, ByVal ColNum As Long)

'This function sends a XML HTTP request, as is much more faster than waiting for browser to DoEvents
'Usage -> Goes to X-rates website and retrieves the code from conversion

Dim sUrl As String
Dim sContent As String
Dim intMatches As Variant
Dim mtchCnt As Integer
Dim subMtchCnt As Integer


sUrl = "http://www.x-rates.com/average/?from=" & sFromCrcy & "&to=" & sToCrcy & "&amount=1&year=" & sYear

'XML Object that queries the website and retrieves HTML as text
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHttp")
    .Open "GET", sUrl, False
    .send
    sContent = .responseText
End With

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = "<span class=""avgRate"">(.*?)</span>"

    Set intMatches = .Execute(sContent)

    If intMatches.Count <> 0 Then
        With intMatches
            For mtchCnt = 0 To .Count - 1
                For subMtchCnt = 0 To .Item(subMtchCnt).SubMatches.Count - 1
                    GetRateYear = .Item(mtchCnt).SubMatches(0)
                    Cells(RowNum, ColNum).Value = GetRateYear
                    Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = sYear
                    Cells(RowNum, 2).Value = sFromCrcy
                    RowNum = RowNum + 1
                Next
            Next
        End With
    End If
  End With
  End Function
```

GetSingleMonth Function:

```
 Private Function GetSingleMonth(ByVal sFromCrcy As String, ByVal sToCrcy As String, ByVal sYear As String, ByVal RowNumB As Long, ByVal ColNumB As Long)

'This function sends a XML HTTP request, as is much more faster than waiting for browser to DoEvents
'Usage -> Goes to X-rates website and retrieves the code from conversion

Dim sUrl As String
Dim sContent As String
Dim intMatches As Variant
Dim mtchCnt2 As Long
Dim subMtchCnt2 As Long

sUrl = "http://www.x-rates.com/average/?from=" & sFromCrcy & "&to=" & sToCrcy & "&amount=1&year=" & sYear

'XML Object that queries the website and retrieves HTML as text
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHttp")
    .Open "GET", sUrl, False
    .send
    sContent = .responseText
End With

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = "<span class=""avgMonth"">(.*?)</span>"

    Set intMatches = .Execute(sContent)

    If intMatches.Count <> 0 Then
        With intMatches
            For mtchCnt2 = 0 To .Count - 1
                GetSingleMonth = .Item(mtchCnt2).SubMatches(0)
                Cells(RowNumB, ColNumB).Value = GetSingleMonth
                RowNumB = RowNumB + 1
            Next
        End With
    End If
  End With
  End Function
```

Styling functions:

```
Private Sub FormatResultSheet()

'We will center the cells to give a better readability of results and format as text to keep all zeros . Ex: 1.000000
Dim TargetRange As Range
Set TargetRange = ResultSheet.Range("A:F")
TargetRange.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
TargetRange.NumberFormat = "@"

End Sub

 Private Sub AddHeader()

'Header cells exist to represent what values are extracted in what columns and are "styled" to stand out for better readability
With ResultSheet
    .Range("A1", "F1").Style = "Input"
    .Range("A1", "F1").Font.Bold = True
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Year"
    .Cells(1, 2).Value = "OffSetCurr"
    .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Month"
    .Cells(1, 4).Value = "toEuro"
    .Cells(1, 5).Value = "toDollars"
    .Cells(1, 6).Value = "toPounds"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Also, a big shout out to @Mat'sMug for helping!

Comment: And to  @Raystafarian who helped so much in this quest!

Comment: Trust me, this is **not** long VBA code.

Comment: I think the code block might have messed up your indentation - take a look at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using Functions

Functions should be used when something is *returned* and subs should be used when something *happens*. Since nothing is being returned to the procedure via the `Functions` they should be `Sub`s, which can still take arguments:

```
Private Sub GetRateYear(ByVal sFromCrcy As String, ByVal sToCrcy As String, ByVal sYear As String, ByVal RowNum As Long, ByVal ColNum As Long)
```

If it was instead `Private Function GetRateYear(...)` you should need to give it a type:

```
Private Function GetRateYear GetRateYear(ByVal sFromCrcy As String, ByVal sToCrcy As String, ByVal sYear As String, ByVal RowNum As Long, ByVal ColNum As Long) as String
```

---

#### For Each String?

Does this work for you -

```
Dim SCrcy As String
For Each SCrcy In Array("EUR", "USD", "GBP")
```

It shouldn't let you use a `String` in a `For Each` loop. It would be better with a `Long`

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 to 3
    Array(i)
```

---

#### Calling procedures

Still, no need to `Call`

```
Call GetSingleMonth("ARS", SCrcy, Period, RowNumB, ColNumB)
Call FormatResultSheet
Call AddHeader
```

They should work without the call.

---

#### Using Constants

You use this twice

```
sUrl = "http://www.x-rates.com/average/?from=" ....
```

Might as well just make that a Global constant:

```
Public Const baseURL As String = "http://www.x-rates.com/average/?from="
sUrl = baseURL & sFromCrcy & "&to=" & sToCrcy & "&amount=1&year=" & sYear
```

That would be declared at the module scope and can be used in any procedures in the module. The same could be said for the usage of `"AUD"`

---

#### For without Next

```
    For i = 1 To 9
```

I think you missed the `Next` for this before the error handler - it won't compile without that.

---

#### Efficiency With Arrays

```
With resultsheet
    .Range("A1", "F1").Style = "Input"
    .Range("A1", "F1").Font.Bold = True
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Year"
    .Cells(1, 2).Value = "OffSetCurr"
    .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Month"
    .Cells(1, 4).Value = "toEuro"
    .Cells(1, 5).Value = "toDollars"
    .Cells(1, 6).Value = "toPounds"
End With
```

This can be more efficient using an array:

```
Dim arr(1 To 6) As String
arr(1) = "Year"
arr(2) = "OffSetCurr"
arr(3) = "Month"
arr(4) = "toEuro"
arr(5) = "toDollars"
arr(6) = "toPounds"

resultsheet.Range("A1:F1") = arr()
```

---

#### Variables

*Variable names* - give your variables meaningful names. Characters are free! Also [standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other variables and names.

```
Dim RowNum As Long - rowNumber
Dim ColNum As Long - columnNumber
Dim RowNumB As Long - nextRow
Dim ColNumB As Long - nextColumn
Dim i As Long
Dim Period As String - period
Dim SCrcy As Variant - sourceCurrency?
Dim MsgErr As String - errorMessage
```

---

#### Inputbox Arguments

I thought this was cute

```
Period = Application.InputBox("What's the year you want to collect back data?", "Period", , , , , 2)
```

You don't need to give it the `null` [arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx):

```
period = Application.Inputbox("What's the year you want to collect back data?","Period",HelpContextID:=2)
```

Though, I think you were aiming at `Type:=`. And if you're going to start being explicit, just make the whole thing explicit:

```
period = Application.Inputbox(Prompt:="What's the year you want to collect back data?", Title:="Period", Type:=2)
```

---

#### Checking User Input

I am not sure what's happening here

```
If Len(Period) <> 4 Then
    GoTo ErrHandler
    Exit Sub
End If
```

`GoTo ErrHandler` will skip the `Exit Sub`. But, `err.Number` will = 0 so the `ErrHandler` won't do its thing. If you don't want to tell the user what they did wrong you can just

```
If Len(period) <> 4 then Exit Sub
```

Otherwise, I'd let them know

```
If Len(period) <> 4 then
   msgbox "Please use 4 digits. Exiting procedure"
   Exit Sub
End if
```

Or, give them another chance.

```
period = GetPeriod
If IsEmpty(period) then Exit Sub
```

with a function:

```
Private Function GetPeriod() As Long
    Dim period As Long
    Dim cancel As String
GetInput:
    period = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="What's the year you want to collect back data?", Title:="Period", Type:=2)

    If Len(period) <> 4 Then
        MsgBox "Please use four digits"
        cancel = MsgBox("Would you like to cancel", vbYesNo)
        If cancel = vbYes Then Exit Function
        GoTo GetInput
    End If
    GetPeriod = period
End Function
```

You could just leave it as it is and assign a custom `Err.Number` for the handler, but I don't have an example of that.

Comment: I can't seem to remove the `Call` from `GetRateYear` and `GetSingleMonth`, since I have made them as sub (as awsomely told me) and it now gives an error, so I've done this: `Dim yearRate as String   yearRate = GetRateYear(AUD sourceCurrency, period, rowNumber, columnNumber) `. Is it ok like this?

Comment: If you have arguments place them to the right, if that doesn't work, put them in paranthesis